# Preimage of homologous points are homologous

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given a (connected) topological space $X$, a contractable space $Y$ and a continuous surjective map $f:X\to Y$, can we say anything about the homology of $X$?

In particular, I have heard it claimed that for any two $y_1, y_2\in Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(y_1)$ is homologous to the preimage $f^{-1}(y_2)$.

I cannot see why this would be true, at least without further conditions on $f$ and $X$.

Comment: What does it mean that two subspaces of $X$ are homologous?

Comment: Let $X$ be any space and let $Y$ be a point. You won't be able to say anything meaningful about $X$ just knowing that there is a continuous surjection to $Y$.

Comment: Take any two based spaces $(X_0, x_0)$ and $(X_1, x_1)$, and let $X = X_0 \cup [0,1] \cup X_1$ where $x_0$ is attached to $\{0\}$ and $x_1$ is attached to $\{1\}$.  Take $f: X \to [0,1]$ to be the quotient map collapsing $X_0$ to $\{0\}$ and $X_1$ to $\{1\}$.  Then $f^{-1}(0) = X_0$ and $f^{-1}(1) = X_1$, but I don't think you can say very much about $X_0$ and $X_1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than I believed. Roughly speaking

Recall that if $A\subset X$, then $x\in \delta A$ implies $f(x) \in\delta f(A)$.

Taking $A=f^{-1}(Y\setminus \{y_1,y_2\})$, the result follows upon showing $A$ to be a chain

Comment: What if $A$ is empty?

Comment: Excellent point. This won't work if A is empty or if Y is a point as you mentioned above. Some conditions are needed on Y that I can't quite make precise, but I think the condition that $f$ be surjective and additionally requiring $Y\setminus\{y_1,y_2\}$ be a non empty open set should be sufficient